# How best to interact with AWS RDS Postgres via NiFi

Tags: python, amazon-rds, apache-nifi

I have a FlowFile and I want to insert the attributes into RDS.  If this was a local machine, I'd create a DBCPConnectionPool, reference a JDBC driver, etc.

With RDS, what am I supposed to do?  Something similar (how would I do this on AWS)?  Or am I stuck using ExecuteScript?  If it's the later, is there a Python example for how to do this?

Comment: what about using PutSQL processor for insertion?

Comment: If you can tell me how to configure the PutSQL processor to work with RDS in an answer, then I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question might not have been clear based on the feedback, but here is the answer to get a NiFi (running on an AWS EC2 instance) communicating with an Amazon RDS instance:

1. On the EC2 instance, download the latest JDBC driver (`wget "https://driver.jar"`)
2. (If needed) Move the JDBC driver into a safe folder.
3. Create the DBCPConnectionPool, referencing the fully-resolved file path to the driver.jar (helpful: use `readlink -f driver.jar` to get the path).
4. Don't forget -- under your AWS Security Groups, add an inbound rule that allows your EC2 instance to access RDS (under **Source**, you should put the security group of your EC2 instance).

Comment: #2 is not best practice, you should avoid putting any JARs into the lib/ folder. Instead put it somewhere else and set the Database Driver Location(s) property in DBCPConnectionPool to that location.

Answer (score 0):

assume that all the values that you want to insert into database are in flowfile attributes.

use `ReplaceText` processor to replace content of the flow file with sql insert statement:

```
insert into mytable (id, message, start_date) values(?, ?, ?)
```

then use `PutSQL` processor with following properties to specify three parameters (`?`) of sql statement

```
sql.args.1.type   = 2               # NUMERIC
sql.args.1.value  = ${MY_ATTR_ID}   # get value from attribute or context variable MY_ATTR_ID

sql.args.2.type   = 12              # VARCHAR
sql.args.2.value  = ${MY_ATTR_MSG}

sql.args.3.type   = 93              # TIMESTAMP
sql.args.3.value  = ${MY_ATTR_DATE}
sql.args.3.format = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

all the jdbc data types are listed here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.ARRAY

Comment: This doesn't explain how to establish the connection to RDS from NiFi

Comment: i thought it's not a problem because you described it in your question ) ... just like you described. put [jdbc driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html#java-rds-drivers) into lib folder. create DbcpConnectionPool..

Comment: Ahh, apologies for the confusion.  If I put it in lib folder, how should I reference it under the "Controller Service Details" "Database Driver Location(s)"?  Fully-resolved path or just the driver name?

Comment: `Database Driver Location` is a parameter to specify where jdbc driver (jar file) is located relative to nifi root folder or absolute path. It's optional when  driver (jar file) is in `nifi/lib` folder.